# UIImage imageNamed not returning image object in iOS 11

Tags: objective-c, null, uiimage, ios11, imagenamed

The following code returns an image object from `path` and works previous to iOS 11:

```
NSString *path = [anotherPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:file];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:path];
```

However in iOS 11, `image` returns `null`. Is this an iOS 11 bug?

Comment: Have you checked that **path** is being set correctly?  I.e., do something like this?:  `NSLog(@"path='%@'", path);`

Comment: Yes I have, and that's why this is strange. The exact same code works in iOS 8 but not in iOS 11. In both versions I can see the exact same path.

Answer (score 1):

`+[UIImage imageNamed:]` is documented as taking a filename, not a path. If you want to load an image from a path, use `+[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:]`.

If your path here is referring to something in a nested folder in your bundle, you can ask `NSBundle` for the path for the resource and then pass that to `+[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:]`. This would look like

```
NSString *path = [NSBundle.mainBundle pathForResource:@"foo" ofType:@"jpg" inDirectory:@"dir"];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Comment: Now I'm even more confused. When I log `[NSBundle.mainBundle pathForResource:@"foo" ofType:@"png" inDirectory:@"dir"]` the image is located in iOS 8 but not in iOS 11 (!?).

Answer (score 0):

As @drewster pointed out, the path was incorrect; I had a lower case character. However, I noticed iOS 8 ignored this.